# How do I unhover on a link using CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm using CSS to set my links to red when I hover over them. Clicking on them would open a new tab, but my links would remain hovered(red). Is it possible to unhover on a button click? This looks really bad, especially on mobile.

```
CSS:
a:hover {
color: red;
}

HTML:
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">Open site in new tab, remains red</a>
```

Comment: I believe its state is focus not hover. You could possibly add a different style for the focused state.

Comment: I think you must use  `a:focus{ some css }` !

Answer (score 0):

The state of the link i.e. `a` tag is `focus` after we have just clicked on it and have not clicked anywhere else. So, most probably you want to change the style for `:focus` state of your anchor tag.

```
CSS:
a:hover {
color: red;
}
a,
a:focus
{
  color: green; /* or whichever is your default color */
}

/* You can also add same or different style for a:visited state, which applies to anchor tags which have been visited */

HTML:
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">Open site in new tab, remains red</a>
```

Comment: Moreover you can style the `a:visited`-state if you want to.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I tried both focus and visited, but it doesn't seem to work that well for mobile. On iOS safari, if I open a link that to a site that has a mobile version(opening linkedin website opens the linkedin app instead) and switch back to Safari, the link would still remain red. Is there a way to unfocus after clicking?

Comment: @iamarnold That red color goes away if you click on some other link, or somewhere else on the code?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes it goes away if I click somewhere, but it doesn't look that good on mobile if the user has to tap on somewhere else for the focus to go away.

Comment: @iamarnold try with `a:focus{ color: green !important; }`. I think :focus should solve your problem, but something might be overriding your style. So, adding `!important` should help.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Tried that and it's not working. This problem only occurs if my link opens an app. It works fine with opening tabs with website.

Answer (score 0):

One way is on click you can add a class to the button that has the original background color when its not being hovered or clicked..

*(This example uses Jquery)*

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('button-onclick');
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
.button-onclick:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">clickers</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/hL4dt60k/